# Qt secure web sockets

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I'm working on a Qt application which communicates with my web browser (currently Google Chrome) through websockets. I have a Chrome extension that injects javascript scripts into some webpages (such as youtube) and open a websocket to my Qt application:

```
var websock = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:52132');
```

And on the Qt side, I have a `QWebSocketServer`:

```
server = new QWebSocketServer("My Server", 
                              QWebSocketServer::SslMode::NonSecureMode, 
                              this) ;
connect(server, &QWebSocketServer::newConnection, 
        this, &MyWidget::onNewConnection) ;
```

And the `onNewConnection` slot:

```
QWebSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection () ;
```

This is not the exact code but it's currently working. Unfortunately, **I can't inject my javascript on https page**, because I am using non-secure websockets.

So I tried using secure websockets, changing `ws://localhost:52132` to `wss://localhost:52132` and `NonSecureMode` to `SecureMode`, but it's not working either if the server is successfully started on the specified port.

I got the following information from Qt when starting my application:

```
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to either:

- Use websockets the way I want? (i.e. a javascript secure websocket communicating with a `QWebSocketServer`
- Use non secure websockets on https pages? Only within scripts injected by my Chrome extension.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you installed OpenSSL libraries on your system?

Comment: @Nejat Yes, and `QSslSocket::supportsSsl ()` returns true. I am using Visual Studio 2013 to build my program, I'm currently looking for the correct way to link openssl but I didn't find anything...

Comment: I think you should also copy `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` from the `\bin` folder to the same place where your `QtNetwork4.dll` is located.

Comment: @Nejat I already did that but it didn't work. I will try to build Qt with OpenSSL when I have more free time.

Comment: did you get any solution ? I have the same problem, trying to connect Qt cleint to node Js Server, i'm getting the same warning, even if i don't want to use ssl.

Comment: @Xsmael I have given up a long time ago, but my problem was the opposite of yours I think (connecting a JS WebSocket to a Qt WebSocketServer).

Comment: oh no, i really needed this to work, ok, anyway i'll keep trying and see.... uhh btw wich OS where you using ?

Comment: @Xsmael I was on Windows 8.1.